# How to use beans from @Import class from an inherited class?

Tags: java, spring

I have a config class B which uses the @Import annotation to import config class A, in this manner

```
@Configuration
@Import({A.class})
public class B {
...
}
```

Now I have a class C which extends class B, but I am not able to access methods of class A from that. How can I do this ?

P.s I can only edit class C since rest are libraries

Comment: I think you should learn first what `@Import` means. Please visit https://www.baeldung.com/spring-import-annotation

Comment: Hi @Saurabh, have gone through articles on this but did not clear my question, can you pl direct ?

Comment: Do you mean to say you are not able to access methods using `@Autowired` injection?

Comment: no, it gives the error ```Could not autowire. No beans of 'x' type found. ```. My class C is also a @Configuration annotated class however dont think that should be an issue